# Create a column within a Bs4card in Shiny

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, bs4dash

I have a bs4card where i would like to add 2 selectize inputs side by side. As you can see from the attached photo, the selectize inputs are squished even with the width of the columns set to 6.

Below is my code...

```
bs4Card(
      width =6,
      title = "Position Re-Balancer",
      collapsible = F,
      closable = F,
      maximizable = T,
      elevation = 2,
 
  #block of code which we are looking at
  fluidRow(
  column(width = 6,
  selectizeInput("bullpos", "Bull", choices = l.etfs$Bull)
  ),
  column(width = 6,
  numericInput("positionbull", "Bull Shares", value = -100)
  )
  ),
  
  selectizeInput("bearpos", "Bear", choices = l.etfs$Bear),
  numericInput("positionbear", "Bear Shares", value = -100),
  numericInput("moneyallocated", "Max $ Allocation", value = 5000)
  
  
)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a MRE with the UI in which the card is embedded. When I put your card into the card example from the `bs4dash` package, it looks ok. There they use `width = 12` within all cards and define their width with columns around the cards, maybe this works for you?

Comment: hi @starja, I am bit confused on what you are saying. Could you provide an example? Thank you

Comment: see my answer for what I mean @Jordan Wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the adapted example from the `bs4Card` help page. I used your card but set the `width` of the card to 12.

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)

shiny::shinyApp(
  ui = bs4DashPage(
    navbar = bs4DashNavbar(),
    sidebar = bs4DashSidebar(),
    controlbar = bs4DashControlbar(),
    footer = bs4DashFooter(),
    title = "test",
    body = bs4DashBody(
      fluidRow(
        column(
          width = 6,
          bs4Card(
            title = "Closable Box with dropdown", 
            closable = TRUE, 
            width = 12,
            status = "warning", 
            solidHeader = FALSE, 
            collapsible = TRUE,
            cardLabel = bs4CardLabel(
              text = 1,
              status = "danger",
              tooltip = "Hello!"
            ),
            dropdownMenu = dropdownItemList(
              dropdownItem(url = "http://www.google.com", name = "Link to google"),
              dropdownItem(url = "#", name = "item 2"),
              dropdownDivider(),
              dropdownItem(url = "#", name = "item 3")
            ),
            p("Box Content")
          )
        ),
        column(
          width = 6, 
          bs4Card(
            width =12,
            title = "Position Re-Balancer",
            collapsible = F,
            closable = F,
            maximizable = T,
            elevation = 2,
            
            #block of code which we are looking at
            fluidRow(
              column(width = 6,
                     selectizeInput("bullpos", "Bull", choices = c("A", "B"))
              ),
              column(width = 6,
                     numericInput("positionbull", "Bull Shares", value = -100)
              )
            ),
            
            selectizeInput("bearpos", "Bear", choices = c("A", "B")),
            numericInput("positionbear", "Bear Shares", value = -100),
            numericInput("moneyallocated", "Max $ Allocation", value = 5000)
            
            
          ) 
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      hist(rnorm(input$obs))
    })
  }
)
```

Here it looks ok. To better understand where the problem in your code lies, please provide a minimal reproducible example, i.e. a running app with the UI you use.

[image]